Удалить запись из родительской и дочерних таблиц
Есть записи в основной таблице и с помощью внешних ключей на данные записи ссылаются записи из дочерних таблиц. Как удалить запись из всех таблиц?

Внешние ключи имеют опции каскадного удаления. Если включено, то удаляя из основной - данные будет удалены из ссылающихся на нее записей зависимых таблиц. Если выключено - удалить запись не получится, так как это нарушит ограничение целостности внешнего ключа. Так что если затык в том, что каскадное удаление отключено - то включите. Если по каким то соображениям включить нельзя. То вручную удалить данные из зависимых таблиц, потом из основной.

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как правильно удалять данные с 2-х таблиц?
